# List branches which have been merged by rebase

Tags: git, github

I have a repository which has many, many branches which have been merged by rebase through github PRs. Even when merging the branch to `master` would be a fast-forward, github insists on doing a true rebase (to attribute the person who pressed the "merge" button as the author on all commits).

What I'm left with is something like this:

```
* (E) [master]
|
* (D')
|
* (C')
|
| * (D) [feat]
| |
| * (C)
|/
|
* (B)
|
* (A)
```

after `feat` is merged.

I'm looking for a way to programmatically identify these "almost merged" branches, so I can clean them up in a batch, in a similar way that `git branch --all --merged master` would show me ones which had actually been merged (or, of course, fast-forwarded to).

The properties of `feat` that make it "almost merged" and eligible for cleanup are:

- Between `feat` and `master`, all commits have a "parallel," "nearly-identical" commit (in this example, `C` has`C'` and `D` has `D'`).

  - Nearly-identical means:

    - Identical diffs
    - Identical commit messages
    - The same Author and AuthorDate (Commit and CommitDate differ)
  - Parallel means:

    - There are no commits between `feat` and its common ancestor on `master` (`B`, in the example) which don't have a nearly-identical pair on `master`
    - The nearly-identical commits on `master` appear in the same order, and come immediately after the common ancestor (again, `B` here)

The following are graphs denote branches I wouldn't consider "almost merged" under this definition:

```
* (E) [master]
|
* (D')
|
* (C')
|
* (X)
|
| * (D) [feat]
| |
| * (C)
|/
|
* (B)
|
* (A)
```

```
* (E) [master]
|
* (D')
|
* (C')
|
| * (D) [feat]
| |
| * (C)
| |
| * (X)
|/
|
* (B)
|
* (A)
```

```
* (E) [master]
|
* (D')
|
* (C')
|
| * (X) [feat]
| |
| * (D)
| |
| * (C)
|/
|
* (B)
|
* (A)
```

I could probably write a script using `GitPython` to do this, but I'm hoping there's already something out there which can do what I need.

## Qualifiers

- I am aware that github has an option to "automatically delete head branches." I have that enabled on this repository now, but there was a long period where it was not. Consequently, there are hundreds of "almost merged" branches to clean up
- If anyone is aware of a way to make github do a true fast-forward when merging a PR, I will be eternally grateful (and will buy you a coffee on ko-fi or something similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit: now that `git range-diff` exists, see sschuberth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74852078/1256452).

I've actually wanted a command like this myself for a while, so I ended up writing it for real.  The end result, with cleanup and options handling, is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chris3torek/scripts/master/git-hubmerged).  It's only just barely tested and may have bugs; no warranties are implied, as they say.

Rather than testing all branches, it only tests one branch that you name, but it should be easy enough to modify.

#### Explanation of the script, and the code that went into it

Your "almost merged" case can be tested pretty easily by comparing the raw parts of commits: the copies have everything the same *except* the parent, and of course the committer parts that you mentioned.  (Even the parent is the same at the first/last of the copied commits, first/last depending on which way you think of them.)

That is, in:

```
* (E) [master]
|
* (D')
|
* (C')
|
| * (D) [feat]
| |
| * (C)
|/
|
* (B)
|
* (A)
```

we merely have extra commits (`E`) stacked atop commits that are literally copies of each other except sometimes for the `parent` lines: `D'` = `D` except for parent, and `C'` = `C` (*including* parent in this case).

You had this graph that you called *not* "almost merged":

```
* (E) [master]
|
* (D')
|
* (C')
|
* (X)
|
| * (D) [feat]
| |
| * (C)
|/
|
* (B)
|
* (A)
```

The issue here is that commit `X` sits between `B` and `C'`, which presumably changes its tree.  If commit `X` is literally empty—or is a pair of commits `Q` and `R` where `R` is a revert of `Q`—then `C'` would have the same tree as `C`.  This matters in the code below, because we can either test `C`'s parent, or look directly to see if there is such a commit, to find out.  I don't bother: if there is such a commit and it's *not* empty, or if there are commits that *aren't* reverted, the trees won't match and we will consider the branch "not almost-merged" anyway.  If the commit *is* empty or reverted, it has no effect, and I, at least, would be happy to call it "almost merged".

---

To test if two commits have everything the same except the committer stuff and the parent hash, we just want to compare their Git internal object contents after trimming those lines away.  We can do this with a sed script that we run from the shell:

```bash
trimcommit() {
    git cat-file -p $1 | sed -e '1,/^$/{/^committer /d;/^parent /d;}'
}
commiteq() {
    trimcommit $1 > /tmp/1
    trimcommit $2 > /tmp/2
    cmp -s /tmp/1 /tmp/2
}
```

This rudely uses hard-coded temp file names that it does not clean up; I fixed that later in the real script.  It also has a minor flaw: it removes *all* parent lines, without checking to see if it's the first parent, or additional parents.  So under some unlikely conditions, this could be fooled by merge commits.  I won't bother to fix this bug though.

So, given two arbitrary branch names M (mainline) and F (feature that may be incorporated into mainline), we might now start with this:

```bash
# clean up on exit
trap "rm -f /tmp/left /tmp/right /tmp/1 /tmp/2" 0 1 2 3 15

# Obtain hash IDs on left (mainline) and right (feature) sides.
git rev-list --reverse --topo-order --left-only M...F > /tmp/left
git rev-list --reverse --topo-order --right-only M...F > /tmp/right

# Make sure both sides are nonempty, otherwise we can't really do anything.
if [ ! -s /tmp/left -a ! -s /tmp/right ]; then
    echo cannot help you - check your inputs
    exit 2  # signaling failure to test
fi

# Open the two files for input, and grab the first hash ID from each.
# The reads should succeed because the files are nonempty.
exec 3< /tmp/left 4< /tmp/right
read l <&3
read r <&4

# Look for a mainline commit that matches the topmost feature commit.
# This is our starting point to decide whether F is "almost merged" into M.
while ! commiteq $l $r; do
    # Drop the top-most left-side commit by reading another.
    if ! read l <&3; then
        echo "not almost-merged: right-side commits are missing"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

At this point, we have a couple of options, which we can distinguish by counting the number of lines remaining in the two files, `/tmp/left` (nl) and `/tmp/right` (nr), including the current commit hashes in $l and $r.  Note that because we checked for empty files, these are both at least 1.  I won't do it here (too hard in shell script) but it's worth thinking about:

- nl < nr: F is not merged as there are too few commits remaining.
- nl > nr: F can only be almost-merged if you allow empty or no-op sequences (an empty `X` commit or a `Q` followed by a reverts-Q `R`, in the thought process above).
- nl == nr.

Now, assuming we allow nl > nr, we test each commit, like this:

```bash
# Topmost commits match, so drop them.  Read the remaining right side
# commits and require each left-side commit to match.
while read l <&3 && read r <&4; do
    if ! commiteq $l $r; then
        echo not almost merged
        exit 1
    fi
done

# If there are more lines in /tmp/left, there are some commits
# we're allowing.  We can check for that by trying to read again.
# Here, I don't bother.
echo is almost merged
exit 0
```

Comment: Awesome! This looks like almost exactly what I need (easy to change the behavior with the extra intermediate commits on master -- though you make a compelling argument for why it may not matter.

Comment: BTW I just actually used my `git-hubmerged` script for the first time for real, found some bugs, and fixed them. It's still a pretty limited script but it does the job I wanted it to do.

Comment: You can cut down the candidate list by quite a lot with `git log --all --pretty=%H\ %T\ %at | sort -k2|uniq -D -f1`.

Comment: @jthill: my (macOS) `uniq` lacks `-D`...

Comment: grump. my inner curmudgeon says `brew install bash coreutils findutils` should be required at gunpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I've just hacked together a script that leverages `git-range-diff` to perform the check:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

UPSTREAM_BRANCH=${2:-origin/main}
REMOTE_BRANCHES=$(git branch -r -l origin/* | grep -vE "(HEAD|$UPSTREAM_BRANCH)")
CHECK_BRANCHES=${1:-$REMOTE_BRANCHES}

NUM_BRANCHES=$(echo "$CHECK_BRANCHES" | wc -l)
BRANCH_COUNTER=0

for BRANCH in $CHECK_BRANCHES; do
    BRANCH_COUNTER=$((BRANCH_COUNTER + 1))
    echo -n "[$BRANCH_COUNTER/$NUM_BRANCHES] Commits of branch $BRANCH "

    UNEQUAL_LINES=$(git range-diff $UPSTREAM_BRANCH...$BRANCH | grep -v " = " | wc -l)

    if [ $UNEQUAL_LINES -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "ARE contained in $UPSTREAM_BRANCH."
    else
        echo "are NOT contained in $UPSTREAM_BRANCH."
    fi
done
```

Comment: range-diff is probably the way to go here - upvoted...